# Changing alias or PATH when in certain directories

Tags: command-line, alias

Is there a way to alter an alias or my PATH variable when I `cd` into a particular folder (and vice versa, change the alias back/restore the PATH when I change out of it)? Right now, I have an alias `dc="docker-compose"`, and when I'm in a particular directory, I want to add parameters to that command.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a *shell function* in place of an alias, and have it conditionally add parameters depending on the value of `$PWD`

```
dc ()
{
    case $PWD in
        "path to/somedir")
            set -- foo bar "$@"
        ;;
        *)
            :    
        ;;
    esac;
    docker-compose "$@"
}
```

See also [In Bash, when to alias, when to script, and when to write a function?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30925/in-bash-when-to-alias-when-to-script-and-when-to-write-a-function)

Note that `dc` is also the name of a command-line calculator utility, so you might want to choose a different name.

Comment: Ok, gotta learn about `set`, but makes sense. So if I had multiple projects, I'd need to modify this script per project, right? Could I make this a script? I'd need to include it at the start of my $PATH then, right?

Comment: This is a shell function. To have it automatically available, you include it in your .bashrc. Question was for one project. However, you of course can edit the function to recognize different projects

Comment: @Rohit indeed since it uses a `case` statement you can easily modify it to perform different actions for different values of `$PWD`

Answer (score 0):

For each of the "special" directories, create a `./.set_alias` file containing `alias` command for the aliases, AND a `./.clear_alias` file with corresponding `unalias` commands.

Then, subvert the `cd` builtin.

In your `~/.bashrc`:

```
cd()
{

    [[ -f ./.clear_alis ]] &&;source ./.clear_alis

    # do the "cd"
    [[ -z "$*" ]] && builtin cd $HOME
    [[ -n "$*" ]] && builtin cd "$*"
    
    [[ -f ./.set_alis ]] && source ./.set_alis
}
```

Directories without these files won't be affected.